# Getting exception in build, when adding file_picker package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I added file_picker to pubspec.yaml, tried to build the app, and then I got this error.

```
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-4.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FileUtils.java:186: error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                                                       ^
  symbol:   variable R
  location: class VERSION_CODES
```

I already ran flutter clean, rebuild and tried different versions of this package, but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting compileSdkVersion to 30 in build.gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30

}
```